# How to pass data from JavaScript into ASP.NET code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I trying to pass data from JavaScript variable into code behind asp.net in C#.

is there any better way for passing data to back-end beside using hidden field control?

where JavaScript assign value into hidden field control, then back-end code get the value from hidden field control.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Guys, I found this link similar with what I wanted to do, [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AJAXformautosave.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide API to your back-end through web services and call them from javascript code.

Comment: web services seem like quite complicated in my situation, because I'm implement this in SharePoint

Comment: This approach is platform independent. Javascript can be embedded in Sharepoint web part and web services can be published on same IIS where Sharepoint itself. Of course it's means more work than using hidden field. But if you plan to build complex UI then your efforts will pay off.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out

[Using Page Methods in ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) - powerful features of ASP.NET AJAX is its ability to tie back-end code to the users' browser in the form of JavaScript with the communication all behind the scenes.

Comment: I think, this is something difficult approach than Hidden field

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar - i think this will work behind the scene using ajax so its might be useful