# Pass output from ToDataURL() to method in ASP.NET code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a JavaScript function bound to an ASP button's click event which uses the HTML5 `toDataURL` function to grab the canvas:

```
function getimg ()
{
    try
    {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9).split(',')[1];
    } 
    catch(e) 
    {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL().split(',')[1];
    }
}
```

What's the best way to take the resulting `img` and pass it to a code-behind method? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578750/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-into-asp-net-code-behind) among others and experimented successfully with using a hidden field, but I'm hoping there's a more direct (less indirect?) way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `canvaspixelarray` property.